# Does @property (readonly, retain) have a meaning?

Tags: objective-c, properties, readonly, retain

XCode accepts it. But will retain be applied when I *internally* set the property (no setter outside since readonly but when I initialize the value in a class method) ?

Regards,
Apple92

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason to do this is to allow you to do `@property (retain)` in a class continuation or category. If you don't have the retain on the outer property, you will get a warning about the properties being mismatched.

Answer (score 5):

You might specify `(readonly, retain)` for a publicly-facing property, and then inside your .m, re-define it as `(readwrite, retain)` to be able to assign to it privately. I use this pattern myself occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

it's also nice as a form of interface documentation