# Why give a property both readonly and assign?

Tags: objective-c

If `assign` is a setter, but a property is `readonly`, then it will not be doing any setting, so why use `assign` ?

I am getting this from the [Apple docs on class extensions. In this page,](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) I get why you'd want a public readonly property, then make it privately readwrite, but then why not omit the `assign` from the public `@interface` and just include it in the class extension only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C 2.0 properties: Why both retain and readonly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933489/objective-c-2-0-properties-why-both-retain-and-readonly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a `@property` multiple times (typically because you declare a public `readonly` property in the  header file, and a `readwrite` property in an anonymous category in your .m), the memory management schemes have to match.

So if you have this in your .m:

```
@property (assign, readwrite) NSObject *foo;
```

Then you need this in your header, and the `assign` is mandatory:

```
@property (assign, readonly) NSObject *foo;
```

Comment: Another case where this is useful is a @protocol defining a property as readonly but your implementation wants is to be readwrite :)

Answer (score 0):

If you leave just `(nonatomic)`, the compiler will automatically set the second parameter to `assign`.

Comment: why would a compiler assume `assign` or any other setter when it is set to `readonly`?

Comment: actually i found another good answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894888/does-property-readonly-retain-have-a-meaning

Comment: The example from the page you linked provides the getter and setter for internal (class-only) use, while the `readonly` parameter is valid for outside use. I didn't understand your question earlier.